# SendToTarget GetTarget in BlueTooth Android Chat Sample

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am working on making the BlueTooth Chat Sample working with a remote service instead of a local service (for later use).

But when I try to use the Handler, which is used to display both sent and received messages, an error occurs, which I don't know how to fix :

```
mHandler.obtainMessage(RemoteServiceClient.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

This line sends to the Handler some informations, including the message code (MESSAGE_WRITE) and the content of the buffer (buffer) which I would like to display.

But when I send a message in the application, it crashes and the log shows a nullPointerException, which, I guess, corresponds to the lack of [getTarget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#getTarget%28%29).

My problem is : in the original sample, there is no getTarget (as in my app), but the sendToTarget works perfectly. How can it be explained and how can I make it work in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue using `dispatchMessage` :

```
messageToMainService.what = VALUES_FROM_THREAD;
messageData.putParcelable("pgnParcelable", pgnListParcelable);
messageData.putParcelable("currentLocation", myLocation);
messageData.putLong("timerBoucle", ellapseTime + timeToSleep);
    //messageData.putWhateverYouWant
messageToMainService.setData(messageData);
mHandler.dispatchMessage(messageToMainService);
```

I wonder if this use is correct. Please tell me if it's not